# Make DataFrame from string and losing my columns name

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I want to create DataFrame from string. Example of string is:

```
                      0 2017   IX 2018       X 2018       X 2018       X 2018        
B   ODNOS              1.053    1.075         1.093        103,8        101,7         1.633    1.669     1.701      104,2    101,9
A   Poljoprivreda       907      888           925        102,0        104,2         1.394    1.356     1.420      101,9    104,7
```

My code to create dataframe  is:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(s), header=None, skiprows=5)

df[0] = df[0].ffill()
df[1] = df[0].map(df[1].groupby(df[0]).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df
```

I get this output, but only way to get data frame is to include skiprows,but I lose my first row, which must be my value for my columns name:

```
 0  C   Prerađivačka industrija     769.000     764.000     775.000     100,8   101,4   1.176   1.169   1.187   100,9   101,5
 1  D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje električnom energi...   1.574   1.570   1.647   104,6   104,9   2.459   2.455   2.579   104,9   105,1
```

I need help to create my DataFrame, or maybe there is easier way, thanks....

Comment: What exactly is the `s` in `pd.compat.StringIO(s)`?

Comment: s is string(my data)